# PHP Adding Data to Database

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I've been testing a CRUD interface with PHP and SQLSRV driver but i got stuck on the creating part, i can read the data that alredy was added on the database by id,  but i cant get to work the create data from PHP to the database, when i press the create Button it clears the inputs and shows the errors.

Would like to know if there is something wrong with my code so far.

**PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
require 'database.php';

if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    $iError = null;
    $nError = null;
    $dError = null;
    $tError = null;


    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $Address = $_POST['Address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];


    $valid = true;
     if (empty($id)) {
        $iError = 'add id';
        $valid = false;
    }
    if (empty($name)) {
        $nError = 'add name';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($Address)) {
        $dError = 'add address';
        $valid = false;
    }

    if (empty($phone)) {
        $tError = 'add phone';
        $valid = false;
    }
    if ($valid) {

      $tsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.TEST1 (id, name, Address, phone) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $arr1 = array($id, $name, $Address, $phone);
      $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $arr1 );
      if ( $stmt  === FALSE ){
        echo "New data created";
      }
      else {
        echo "Error creating data";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
      }
    }
}?>`
```

**this is the HTML part:**

```
<body>
<div>


                <div>
                    <h3>CREAR</h3>
                </div>

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="create.php" method="post">

                <div class=" <?php echo !empty($iError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label >ID</label>
                    <div >
                        <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="ID" value="<?php echo !empty($id)?$id:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($iError)): ?>
                            <span ><?php echo $iError;?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class=" <?php echo !empty($nError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label>name</label>
                    <div>
                        <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="name" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($nError)): ?>
                            <span><?php echo $nError;?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class=" <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label >Address</label>
                    <div >
                        <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Address" value="<?php echo !empty($Address)?$Address:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($dError)): ?>
                            <span><?php echo $dError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class=" <?php echo !empty($tError)?'error':'';?>">
                    <label >phoner</label>
                    <div >
                        <input name="mobile" type="text"  placeholder="phone" value="<?php echo !empty($phone)?$phone:'';?>">
                        <?php if (!empty($tError)): ?>
                            <span ><?php echo $tError;?></span>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div >
                      <button type="submit">Create</button>
                      <a  href="index.php">Return</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You are testing if your statement is FALSE, and if it is, you echo that everything went right. It doesn't make sense. Switch it to TRUE.

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: when i press the create just clears the inputs and shows the "errors" i made when inputs are in blank  i'm not getting any errors from the server and the database doesnt update with the data i entered on the inputs when i do the create.